# Socket.io/Node.JS array elements transmission

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an array of canvas elements, and each one is responsible for using the defined functions to interact with these elements.

I do, although have a problem.

Whenever I try to transmit the currently clicked canvas element through socket.io there seems to be a problem recognizing the previousInfo variable, which should store the information for where the cursor has been.

Example:

```
canvas[i].onTouchStart = onTouchStartEventFunction;

canvas[i].onTouchMove = onTouchMoveEventFunction;

canvas[i].onTouchEnd = onTouchEndEventFunction;
```

this creates the canvas array and stores each instance on the array.

The functions:

```
var onTouchStartEventFunction = function(info, index, count, event) {
draw(info.layerX, info.layerY, event.type, info.layerX, info.layerY, this);
    socket.emit('touchevent', {
        x: info.layerX,
        y: info.layerY,
        e: event.type,
        px: info.layerX,
        py: info.layerY,
        idx: this
});
}

var onTouchMoveEventFunction = function(info, index, count, previousInfo, event) {
if(previousInfo === null) 
{} 
else {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "X: " + info.layerX + " Y: " + info.layerY + " pX:" + previousInfo.layerX + " pY:" + previousInfo.layerY;
    draw(info.layerX, info.layerY, event.type, previousInfo.layerX, previousInfo.layerY, this);
    socket.emit('touchevent', {
        x: info.layerX,
        y: info.layerY,
        e: event.type,
        px: previousInfo.layerX,
        py: previousInfo.layerY,
        idx: this
    });
}
}

var onTouchEndEventFunction = function(info, index, count, event) {
draw(info.layerX, info.layerY, event.type, info.layerX, info.layerY, this);
socket.emit('touchevent', {
    x: info.layerX, 
    y: info.layerY,
    e: event.type,
    px: info.layerX,
    py: info.layerY,
    idx: this
});
}
```

Everything works fine if I don't pass the 'idx:this' through sockets, and the previousInfo works as expected.
However, whenever I starting using the 'idx:this' the pX and pY (the previousInfo X and Y coordinates) are always the same, no changes.

The worst is that this happens for every single instance, and wherever I click, the pX and pY points always stay the same.

So, given this, can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

seems like something missing from our problem description, but I would try creating a self invoking function:

```
 var onTouchEndEventFunction = function(info, index, count, event) {
     draw(info.layerX, info.layerY, event.type, info.layerX, info.layerY, this);
     (function (canvas) {
        socket.emit('touchevent', {
            x: info.layerX, 
            y: info.layerY,
            e: event.type,
            px: info.layerX,
            py: info.layerY,
            idx: canvas
    });)(this);
  }
```

Comment: Hi @RobertPeters, I've actually done things a bit different and instead of passing the object I just started passing the index of the object in the array.. Seemed to work, but your answer might be just the right workaround. tks